# Difference between parameterless catch and other catch

Tags: c#, exception

I have there piece of code

```
//Code 1                        Code 2                          Code 3
try                             try                             try
{                               {                               {
    //Exp occur                     //Exp occur                     //Exp occur 
}                               }                               }
catch (Exception e)             catch (Exception)               catch
{                               {                               {
    //Handle exp                    //Handle exp                    //Handle exp
}                               }                               }
```

What is the difference between all of three codes
**P.S.** I'm new to **`C#`** and as far as **`Java`** or **`Objective-C`** is concerned this syntax throws error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Code 1**

Its catching Exception in an object `e` which can be later used for exception handling. For example you can log the Message property or view stack trace using `e.Message` or `e.StackTrace`

**Code 2**

You are catching all the exception of the base type `Exception` but since you don't have any object related to it, you can only throw that exception so that it can bubble up or you may ignore the exception. If in that code you had :

```
catch(InvalidCastException)
```

Then all the `InvalidCastException` will be handled in the block **without the exception object**

**Code 3**

You are catching all type of exceptions irrespective of their type, which is similar to your code 2 with base class `Exception`

[try-catch - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0yd65esw.aspx)

> Although the catch clause can be used without arguments to catch any
>   type of exception, this usage is not recommended. In general, you
>   should only catch those exceptions that you know how to recover from.

Its always better if you catch specific exceptions before catching the base one. Something like.

```
try
{
}
catch(InvalidCastException ex)
{
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

[try - catch - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0yd65esw.aspx)

> It is possible to use more than one specific catch clause in the same
>   try-catch statement. In this case, the order of the catch clauses is
>   important because the catch clauses are examined in order. Catch the
>   more specific exceptions before the less specific ones. The compiler
>   produces an error if you order your catch blocks so that a later block
>   can never be reached.

Answer (score 3):

Code 1 - fairly normal catch, hopefully doesn't need explanation

Code 2 - You want to execute a particular piece of code when a particular exception occurs, but you have no intention of actually interacting with the exception object. Should almost always have a `throw;` statement at the end, so that someone else higher up the stack who does care can `catch` it.

Code 3 - You want the code to execute for *any* exception(*) (except for any caught by earlier `catch` clauses of the same `try`). Again, should almost always include a `throw;` so that higher code can `catch` and actually process the exception.

At some level (possibly just at the top level, in the unhandled exception handlers for whatever environment you're in), *something* ought to be inspecting the exception object and probably logging it (if possible).

Answer (score 2):

Here if you want to use the variable 'e' for getting the Exception message, Line or type.

```
//Code 1                       
try                            
{                              
 //Exp occur                
}                              
catch (Exception e)            
{                              
 //Handle exp               
}
```

Below code for getting particular type of Exception and not dealing with Exception variable.

```
//Code 2
try                            
{                              
  //Exp occur                
}                              
catch (Exception)
{                              
 //Handle exp           
}
```

Below code catching all types of exceptions.

```
//Code 3
try
{
 //Exp occur    
}     
catch 
{                  
 //Handle exp   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you plan to actually use the exception object, to log its properties to a log file or to show a message box or to throw another kind of exception and pass the current exception to its constructor, then you must use the first of the three (most left one).

in general the most used approach is the first one anyway, if you want to handle different kind of exceptions separately you can have multiple catch blocks starting with the most specialized on top and have the one you wrote at the bottom so that all exceptions not already handled will end in the generic catch block.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. They all catch EVERY exception that could possibly occur (by catching base type `Exception` or just any).  This is typically frowned upon, for good reason. You should catch specific exceptions in the order you expect, and then if you do want to catch all exceptions catch `Exception` at the end.

```
try
{
}
catch (MyCustomException)
{
    // do something for your custom exception
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // do something for everything else
}
```

When you specify a variable for your exception such as `catch (Exception e)` you will have access to the stack trace (and other exception information) via `e.Property` or simply `e.ToString()` for the full message. It's also best practice to `throw` the exception when caught (well, unless you want to suppress it at this level and not allow your calling code to see the exception) so it bubbles up and you preserve the stack trace:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    // do something with e

    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code 1 catches every exception (in your  case!) and declares it, so you can use it later e.g. for Error-Messages.

```
MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
```

Code 2 also catches every exception (in your  case!), but you can't use it, because it is not declared.

These two methods are not designed for that, they're designed to catch specific or custom exceptions.

```
    try
    {
     //mycode
    }catch(MyException myExc)
    {   
    //TODO HERE  
    Console.Write(myExc.Message);  
    }
```

The third one catches all exceptions. Because there is no definition.

Take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

to learn more about exceptions in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Differences:

1. **Declaring Exception Parameter ex** allows you to access the Exception object, in order to see and work with its properties, fields, methods and the like. This "ex" variable works like any parameter in any method.
2. **Declaring Exception Type without parameter ex** allows you to separate several "catch" areas for different types of exception. It is useless, and functionally equivalent to *code sample 3* as you define it here, but if you need to do different actions depending on the type of the exception, and you do not need to access the exception object (you only need to know the type of the exception), then this is your way to go.
3. **Untyped Catch Exception Handler** allows you to add a fallback for any Exception that might be thrown, whatever its type. Since it is not parameterized, however, you won't have access to the Exception object's properties or methods. Both *code sample 2* and *code sample 3* therefore are equivalent.

Example:

```
try{ // code that throws exception }
catch(TypeException ex) 
{ 
    // code to handle exceptions of type TypeException
    // I can access ex parameter, for example to show its Message property
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
catch(OtherTypeException) 
{ 
    // code to handle exceptions of type OtherTypeException 
    // I cannot access the ex parameter since it is not declared, but I know
    // the exact type of the exception
    MessageBox.Show("There was an exception of Other Type");
}
catch
{
    // code to handle any other exception
    // this is functionally equivalent to catch(Exception) since all typed exceptions
    // inherit from the base type Exception
    MessageBox.Show("An unknown exception has been thrown.");
}
...
```